# Determining the gradient of a polyfit curve

Tags: python, numpy

Please can anyone help me with how to determine the gradient of a polyfit curve using numpy. This is the code i have written but the gradient seems not to be right after computing it.

```
Func_1 = np.polyfit(time, p, 15)
Func_2 = np.poly1d(Func_1)
time_new = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 200)                   
p_new = Func_2(time_new)                                        
dp_dt = np.gradient(time_new, p_new)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem i just had to interchange the time and pressure position

Answer (score 0):

"it seems not to be right" is not a fact, it's an opinion and you need to back it up with your results and explanation as to why you believe it's wrong.

By the way this can be solved with simple math: the derivative of `x**n` is `n*x**(n-1)`.
So the coefficients of the gradient are simply `Func_1 * np.arange(15+1)[::-1]`.